# How can i optimise this PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql-9.3

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id,
 --   ( SELECT count(sfcm.id) AS count
 --          FROM master.flip_class_master sfcm
 --         WHERE sfcm.chapter_id = cm.id AND sfcm.publish_state::text = 
 -- 'PUBLISHED'::text AND sfcm.is_active = true) AS total_flip_class,
    sum(
        CASE
            WHEN (fcp.viewed_duration::double precision / fcp.total_duration::double precision * 100::double precision)::integer > 20 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS viewed_flip_class,
    avg((fcp.viewed_duration::double precision / fcp.total_duration::double precision * 100::double precision)::integer)::integer AS viewed_percentage,
    fcp.user_id,
    currm.subject_code,
    date(fcp.modified_date) AS modified_date
   FROM master.flip_class_master fcm
     JOIN master.chapter_master cm ON cm.id = fcm.chapter_id AND cm.active
     JOIN master.curriculam_master currm ON currm.id = cm.curriculam_id AND currm.active = true
     LEFT JOIN master.flipclass_progress fcp ON fcp.flip_class_masters = fcm.id
  WHERE fcm.publish_state::text = 'PUBLISHED'::text AND fcm.is_active = true
  GROUP BY fcp.user_id, currm.subject_code, (date(fcp.modified_date)), cm.id;
```

master(schema_name).##(table_name

if i remove above 4 dotted line code then is responding quickly but if i insert those its taking 9 sec of time.

What will be the solution?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` before the query (explain select...) and look at the plan. If there is a `sequential scan` somewhere, you can improve that by adding an index.